# Tomcat 7 won't start on eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I've installed eclipse Kepler with JAVA EE plugin on ubuntu. 
Then I installed `Apache Tomcat/7.0.35`, but when I start the server from `Servers` tab, I get this error message :

> Several ports (8005, 8080) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost
>   are already in use. The server may already be running in another
>   process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this
>   server you will need to stop the other process or change the port
>   number(s).

And when I open this link `http://localhost:8080/` it works fine.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that's not the installed copy running on that port, as the error message all but says?

Answer (score 0):

Run netstat -aon and look for ports 8080 or 8005 and kill the process with

```
taskkill /f /pid (pid of process)
```

if your running linux or mac you enter top and look for the process and run:

```
 kill (pid of process)
```

Then just restart the server